# I am getting LinkedHashSet instead of Classes in below attached code snippet

Tags: pojo

I want to implement POJO that will contain small POJO's inside master POJO. As well all configuration needs to be read from YAML file, while running my spring boot application I am getting always LinkedHashSet, it will require too much validation at application level and retrieval will be complex.
Please help me.

```
resilience:
  config:
    default:
      datasource:
        circuitBreaker:
          slidingWindowSize: 10
          slidingWindowType: count
          minimumNumberOfCalls: 5
          permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 3
          slowCallRateThreshold: 50.0f
          slowCallDurationThreshold: 2
          waitDurationInOpenState: 5
          failureRateThreshold: 50.0f
          recordExceptions: [ ReadTimeOut.class, NumberFormatException.class ]
        retry:
          maxAttempts: 3
          waitDuration: 2
    rds:
      datasource:
        circuitBreaker:
          slidingWindowSize: 10
          slidingWindowType: time;
          minimumNumberOfCalls: 5
          permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 3
          slowCallRateThreshold: 50.0f
          slowCallDurationThreshold: 2
          waitDurationInOpenState: 5
          recordExceptions: [ ReadTimeOut.class, NumberFormatException.class ]
        retry:
          maxAttempts: 3
          waitDuration: 0
```

````
import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Component("circuitBreakerProperties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "resilience")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class CircuitBreakerProperties {
    private Map<String, Datasource> config;
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    private static class Datasource{
        private CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker;
        private Retry retry;
    }
    private static class CircuitBreaker {
        private int slidingWindowSize=10;
        private String slidingWindowType="COUNT";
        private int minimumNumberOfCalls=5;
        private int permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState=3;
        private float slowCallRateThreshold=50.0f;
        private int slowCallDurationThreshold=2;
        private int waitDurationInOpenState=5;
        private List<?> recordExceptions=new ArrayList<>();
    }
    private static class Retry {
        private int maxAttempts=3;
        private int waitDuration=0;
    }
}```
````